# Converting from time.h tzname[0] to Java TimeZone

Tags: java, c++, timezone, simpledateformat, time.h

I'm writing a service that converts Windows timezone values from calling _tzname[0] (time.h, C++) into Java timezone using SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone. I'll be getting these values from a REST service so it will only be a String when I get the values from the external service (which uses_tzname[0]).

Example:

```
String windowsTimeZoneID = "?"; // External value from _tzname[0] REST service
windowsTimeZoneID = "some converted value"; // I'll need to convert the value
final TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(windowsTimeZoneID);

final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yykkmm");
DATE_FORMAT.setTimeZone(timeZone);
```

Note: when the external service calls _tzname[0], they strip out "Standard Time" so if _tzname[0] returned "Eastern Standard Time", the service only returns "Eastern".

Is there a list of possible values that _tzname[0] can have?

Edit: I should mention, I don't have control to change the REST service implementation and what it returns (_tzname[0] from time.h)

Comment: Related: check out Howard Hinnant's date library

Comment: `_tzname` only returns values reflected from the `TZ` variable, which is generally **not set** in Windows because it's only honored by the C Runtime, for POSIX compliance.  It doesn't return a value that reflects the time zone selected by the user in Windows.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Since you say you aren't calling that function but the REST service is and you have no ability to change it, then sorry but you're kinda screwed.  If the REST service is indeed getting the system time zone via `_tzname[0]`, it is feeding you garbage.

Comment: Now you mention Eastern Standard Time, I was going to say it’s not a time zone. However, Nunavut and Quintana Roo and a few other places in Central America are on EST all year round, so maybe it’s valid to regard it as one. However, it’s still true that most of the places in the Eastern time zone are only on EST during the shorter part of the year. Just to complicate things…

Comment: Link to HowardHinnant’s date and time library: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date. I don’t know it, but it certainly looks relevant and helpful.